# New User Registration hitting: Protected protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, registration

I working on an ASP.NET MVC Project. I have created for following Models Controllers and Views for a User Registration:

- Model Name: "**AccountViewModels.cs**" (sub-model "RegisterViewModel")
- Controller Name: "**AccountController.cs"** ( Register(RegisterViewModel model) is the *ActionTask*)
- View Name: "**Account**" (Register.cshtml)

When I run it I get to the register page without any problems. However once I submit the New Register User Details, I can see the code disposing my users input to the following:

```
 protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && UserManager != null)
            {
                UserManager.Dispose();
                UserManager = null;
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
```

Then receive the following message in Chrome:

## Server Error in '/' Application.

*The system cannot find the file specified*

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

**Source Error:**

```
{
    var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
    IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {}
}
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you post how you're rendering the view?

Comment: When you debug is UserManager null?

Comment: @lloydm When I debug the "UserManager" is null (true).

Comment: @JimSchubert Rendering a Form in ASP.NET MVC Using HTML Helpers.

Comment: Why is UserManager = null; required if you've already disposed of it? please show code where this is set to a new instance of a object and your initial instantiation.